# changing text in html with php without affecting html tags

Tags: php

i've edited a simple php function to convert the letters to the homograph with similar look.

my code :

```
function homographit($string){

$alphabet = array("A", "B", "C", "E", "H", "J", "K", "M", "N", "O", "P", "S", "T", "X", "Y", 
"a", "b", "c", "e", "i", "j", "k", "o", "p", "r", "s", "v", "x", "y");
$Greec   = array("\u0391", "\u0392", "\u0421", "\u0395", "\u0397", "\u0408", "\u039A", "\u039C", "\u039D", "\u039F", "\u03A1", "\u0405", 
"\u03A4", "\u03A7", "\u03A5", "\u0430", "\u042C", "\u0441", "\u0435", "\u0456", "\u0458", "\u03BA", "\u03BF", "\u03C1", "\u0433", "\u0455", 
"\u03BD", "\u03C7", "\u0443");

$newstring = str_replace($alphabet, $Greec, $string);
return json_decode('"'.$newstring.'"', true);
}
```

for a text string the function work as perfect.

My question:

How to apply this homgraphit() to all text in html string withouwt affecting html TAGS?
thx

Comment: by using regex on `<` characters and `>` - also range('A', 'Z') will get an alphabet quicker than typing it all

Comment: thank you freind .any idea to do it i want to change only  the alphabet quoted in my function not all alphabet

Comment: no worries :) w.i.mm.n's answer looks good (I havent tested, but I trust his/her word) :) and don't worry, I didn't see that it was only a few letters, not all of them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've solved my probblem with the

```
preg_replace_callback()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strip_tags` built-in php function for Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string. Im tested with code bellow using your `homographit` function:

```
$x = '<span>\u0391</span><b>\u0392</b>';
$x = strip_tags($x);
var_dump(homographit($x));die();

//will print
//string(4) "ΑΒ"

$x = '<span>\u0391</span><b>\u0392</b>';
var_dump(homographit($x));die();

//will print
//string(32) "<ѕρаn>Α</ѕρаn><Ь>Β</Ь>"
```

hope this can solve your problem.

Edit
i found this

```
$x = '<span>\u0455\u0391</span><b>\u0392</b>';
$convertedString = json_decode('"' . $x . '"');
var_dump($convertedString);

// will print
// string(26) "<span>ѕΑ</span><b>Β</b>"
```

try this

Comment: thank you w-i-mm-n ; i've tested strip_tags and echo homographit($html) .i wnat to change text in html without affecting for example <a or <p html tags

Comment: oh so you want to output like <span>A</span><b>B</b>, if like that you just pass all your html string to your function, than it would output like that. i just edit sample above.

Comment: look for this tags: <Ь> it's affected it's changed with my fucntionalso this one <ѕρаn>: the p in span is changed to greec charcters

Comment: i just edit my answer, html tag is not touch, only convert \uxxxx with json_decode, no use homographit function. is that you looking for?